# Smarty how to parse URL in template file

Tags: php, smarty

How would I translate this PHP statement: `$domain = str_ireplace('www.', '', parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST));` to a smarty function such as:`{$url|str_ireplace:'something':'etc'}`

I want to print $domain in this case. $url is a smarty variable that is set for a certain URL. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe multiple modifiers, to first extract the host and then strip the `www.`:

```
{$url|parse_url:$smarty.const.PHP_URL_HOST|replace:'www.':''}
```

So for:

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/foo/bar.html';
```

It prints:

```
example.com
```